# How can I override/shadow another module's function? Something like a shim or a LD_PRELOAD trick

Tags: python

How can I override functions from a different module in Python?
 What I'm trying to achieve is to capture all filesystem related calls, so I want all modules that use builtin.open, builtin.read, etc to call the functions of my module, instead of builtin's. I want to do this so that I don't have to modify all the modules that use builtin.

I could use LD_PRELOAD to capture this at the lower layer but, unfortunately, it isn't available to me, so I'm trying to find a way to do this in Python.

An example would be a script using [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html):

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(infile)
im.thumbnail(size)
im.save(file + ".thumbnail", "JPEG")
```

On thumbnail and save, PIL will call builtin.open, read and write. What can I do to capture those function calls?
  Is there any solution that doesn't involve changing the interpreter or the builtin module itself? 
 Is there any trick that I can do like creating a module with the same name and loading it first on the script that imports PIL? Similar to LD_PRELOAD?

The only idea that I have that would work is to change the builtin module itself, but if there's a simpler one out there, I'd rather use it.

Comment: I think the colloquial term you're looking for is "monkey patching," but keep in mind that anything defined/implemented within C extensions will be immutable. This includes the builtins. Only Python-defined classes and objects can be monkey patched as the libraries written in C are shared between multiple instances of the Python interpreter and patching them would affect other instances. There's some leeway with libraries like https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit but I doubt it's exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change open to any function you want to, **but** this might not work for all modules/functions:

```
import builtins
builtins.oldOpen = builtins.open . # keep original open function!

def myOpen(*args, **kwargs):
    print("myOpen")
    return builtins.oldOpen(*args, **kwargs)

builtins.open = myOpen
print (open('/tmp/f.py'))
```

Output:

```
myOpen
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/tmp/f.py' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

Comment: I'll check if this changes the functions from builtins across all modules and report back, if that works it would be perfect.

Comment: Seems like it's working. Tested against PIL's Image.open and it calls that one. I wonder if `open` points to `builtins.open`, then this would work for implicit calls too. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, `builtins.open` and `open` are the same function.