# "Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp"? How do you avoid this error?

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array, stringindexoutofbounds

I have an array, recognised as a 'numpy.ndarray object' which prints the following output when running the following code:

```
with sRW.SavReaderNp('C:/Users/Sam/Downloads/Data.sav') as reader:
record = reader.all()
print(record)
```

Output:

```
[(b'61D8894E-7FB0-3DE6-E053-6C04A8C01207', b'Sam', 250000., '2019-08-05T00:00:00.000000')
 (b'61D8894E-7FB0-3DE6-E053-6C04A8C01207', b'James',  250000., '2019-08-05T00:00:00.000000')
 (b'61D8894E-7FB0-3DE6-E053-6C04A8C01207', b'Mark', 250000., '0001-01-01T00:00:00.000000')
```

I  really want to process empty date variables within a pandas DataFrame using pd.DataFrame format, but when I run the following code an error appears (as shown bellow the code):

```
SPSS_df = pd.DataFrame(record)
```

> Error: "Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:00:00"

I've read through the source code of SavReader Module Documentation and it says if a Datetime value is not found, the following date is assigned:

```
datetime.datetime(datetime.MINYEAR, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

I wondered how could I process this date without encountering this error, perhaps changing/maniuplating this code above?

Comment: Why don't you convert `record` to a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Because an error occurs. If a date variable is missing from the SPSS file. So I'm trying to change it before i convert it to a  pandas dataframe

Comment: Can you try this? First, `import numpy as np`, than change reading to: `with sRW.SavReaderNp('C:/Users/Sam/Downloads/Data.sav', rawMode=False, recodeSysmisTo=np.nan) as reader:`

Comment: I've tried doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Can you post an exact copy of the output when dates are missing? Is record a `list` of `tuples`?

Comment: value = tslibs.conversion.ensure_datetime64ns(value)
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 123, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.ensure_datetime64ns
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\np_datetime.pyx", line 118, in pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.check_dts_bounds
pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: Ok, and also an exact copy of sample data in `record`? Is it a string or a list of tuples?

Comment: I've show this above, the first two columns are strings hence the b', the next is a float and finally a datetime variable

Comment: If it is a list, you can use a list comprehension like `record = [(x[0], x[1], x[2], np.nan) if x[3] == '0001-01-01T00:00:00.000000' else x for x in record]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200620/discussion-between-sam-and-hoenie).

Comment: Ahh, It’s a numpy.ndarray object? So perhaps an extension to this may help?

Comment: have you thought of overriding the builtin function which assigns the default time.. ? that way you can give the nano seconds the way you want.

Comment: @Sam have you considered [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39905822/out-of-bounds-nanosecond-timestamp?rq=1)? It seems to suggest that either setting an explicit time format string or setting the `dayfirst` field may have previously solved this problem? I'm sure it's super obvious as it's one of the top search results on this error, but thought I'd mention.

Comment: i don't understand your problem, you are not able to create a dataframe using `record`?

Comment: Yes @Yatish Kadam, I'm just not sure how to do this

Comment: @Sam this is a good example of overriding built in functions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58173218/how-can-i-override-shadow-another-modules-function-something-like-a-shim-or-a

Comment: This error occurs when you try to convert date before 1970-01-01. You should google "posix time" for details. In your case, you can read in the datetime as strings, and deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do, is read all the records as strings (object) and after convert the column into the wanted type (float and datetimes)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

record = [
    (
        b'61D8894E-7FB0-3DE6-E053-6C04A8C01207',
        b'Sam',
        250000.0,
        '2019-08-05T00:00:00.000000',
    ),
    (
        b'61D8894E-7FB0-3DE6-E053-6C04A8C01207',
        b'James',
        250000.0,
        '2019-08-05T00:00:00.000000',
    ),
    (
        b'61D8894E-7FB0-3DE6-E053-6C04A8C01207',
        b'Mark',
        250000.0,
        '0001-01-01T00:00:00.000000',
    ),
]

SPSS_df = pd.DataFrame(record, dtype=object).rename(
    {2: 'some_float', 3: 'dates'}, axis='columns'
).assign(
    some_float=lambda x: x['some_float'].astype(np.float),
    dates=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['dates'], errors='coerce'),
)
```

This gives:

```
0  b'61D8894E-7FB0-3DE6-E053-6C04A8C01207'    b'Sam'    250000.0 2019-08-05
1  b'61D8894E-7FB0-3DE6-E053-6C04A8C01207'  b'James'    250000.0 2019-08-05
2  b'61D8894E-7FB0-3DE6-E053-6C04A8C01207'   b'Mark'    250000.0        NaT
```

and the types:

```
SPSS_df.dtypes
0                     object
1                     object
some_float           float64
dates         datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: While this avoids the error I don't have 'NAT' in missing date spaces. I have random dates '1754-08-30 22:43:41.128654'

Comment: Can you give me an example of a missing date spaces?

Comment: Instead of dtype='object', dtype='str' worked? I'm not sure why, and it removed the b' prefix

Comment: The `str` dtype convert all your data into string. Your previous chain of characters were in bytes.